# remove list value when list is in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict, like below, and I want to remove the value `'---'`.

```
{'I1': ['卤味零食',
  '蔬菜干'],
 'I2': ['Three Squirrels/三只松鼠',
  '良品铺子',
  '---',
  '---']}
```

How can I do that in one line?

Comment: `print({k: [i for i in v if i.strip("-")] for k, v in data.items()})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
{x:[y for y in data[x] if '-'*3 not in y] for x in data}
```

**Output**

> {'I1': ['卤味零食', '蔬菜干'], 'I2': ['Three Squirrels/三只松鼠', '良品铺子']}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dict comprehension

**Ex:**

```
data = {'I1': ['卤味零食',
  '蔬菜干'],
 'I2': ['Three Squirrels/三只松鼠',
  '良品铺子',
  '---',
  '---']}
print({k: [i for i in v if i.strip("-")] for k, v in data.items()})
```